# Creating model with contains list of widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

hii i'm a newbie in flutter and now i'm creating screen model(screen_model.dart) like this

```
class ScreenModel{
  final String title;
  final Widget screen;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  ScreenModel({@required this.titleScreen, @required this.widgetScreen, this.actions});
}
```

then when i try to initialize model in main.dart

```
  final List<Widget> defaultActions = [
IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list, color: Colors.white), onPressed: null),
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white), onPressed: null)
];

final List<ScreenModel> _widgetOptions = [
ScreenModel(title: 'Purchasing', screen: PurchasingScreen(),actions: defaultactions)
];
```

i get an error "The instance member 'defaultActions' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression"
how to fix this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use init `_widgetOptions` in `initState()`

```
  List<ScreenModel> _widgetOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _widgetOptions = [
      ScreenModel(
          title: 'Purchasing',
          screen: PurchasingScreen(),
          actions: defaultActions)
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ScreenModel {
  final String title;
  final Widget screen;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  ScreenModel({@required this.title, @required this.screen, this.actions});
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<Widget> defaultActions = [
    IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list, color: Colors.blue), onPressed: null),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.blue), onPressed: null)
  ];

  List<ScreenModel> _widgetOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _widgetOptions = [
      ScreenModel(
          title: 'Purchasing',
          screen: PurchasingScreen(),
          actions: defaultActions)
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: _widgetOptions[0].actions,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PurchasingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome it works,can you please explain why i have to use initState? actually i'm using screen model for switching screen with bottom navigation, everything works before i add list<widget> for custom action into screenModel and i didn't use initstate.

Comment: The system allocates memory for class variables the first time it encounters the class. at that time defaultActions 's memory address is unknown.